# Kafka listener, get all messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Good day collegues.
I have Kafka project using Spring Kafka what listen a definite topic.
I need one time in a day listen all messages, put them into a collection and find specific message there.
I couldn't understand how to read all messages in one @KafkaListener method.
My class is:

```
@Component
public class KafkaIntervalListener {

    public CountDownLatch intervalLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private final SCDFRunnerService scdfRunnerService;

    public KafkaIntervalListener(SCDFRunnerService scdfRunnerService) {
        this.scdfRunnerService = scdfRunnerService;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.interval-topic}", containerFactory = "intervalEventKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void intervalListener(IntervalEvent event) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {
        System.out.println("Recieved interval message: " + event);
        IntervalType type = event.getType();
        Instant instant = event.getInterval();
        List<IntervalEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
        events.add(event);
        events.size();


        this.intervalLatch.countDown();
    }

}
```

My events collection always has size = 1;
I tried to use different loops, but then, my collection become filed 530 000 000 times the same message.

**UPDATE:**
I have found a way to do it with factory.setBatchListener(true); But i need to find launch it with @Scheduled(cron = "${kafka.cron}", zone = "Europe/Moscow"). Right now this method is always is listening. Now iam trying something like this:

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "${kafka.cron}", zone = "Europe/Moscow")
public void run() throws Exception {
    kafkaIntervalListener.intervalLatch.await();
}
```

It doesn't work, in debug mode my breakpoint never works on this site.

Comment: in the current code, you cannot have a list with more than one message, as you create a new instance every time.

Comment: if you need to find only one message, may be it can be easier just to look for it during consuming? (as loading all data in memory is not a good idea)

Comment: The specific message will be calculated depending on the others. I have found a way to do it with factory.setBatchListener(true); But i need to find launch it with @Scheduled(cron = "${kafka.cron}", zone = "Europe/Moscow"). Right now this method is always is listening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener container is, by design, message-driven.

For fetching messages on-demand, it's better to use the Kafka `Consumer` API directly and fetch messages using the `poll()` method.

Comment: Used your advise. My code become cleaner and easyer to use.